# Logical XOR in character arrays

Tags: c, cryptography, bitwise-xor

I've been trying to make a program on Vernam Cipher which requires me to XOR two strings. I tried to do this program in C and have been getting an error.The length of the two strings are the same.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Enter your string to be encrypted ");
    char a[50];
    char b[50];
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("Enter the key ");
    scanf("%s",b);
    char c[50];
    int q=strlen(a);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        c[i]=(char)(a[i]^b[i]);
    }
    printf("%s",c);
}
```

Whenever I run the code, I get output as ????? in boxes. What is the method to XOR these two strings ?

Comment: XOR can produce an unprintable value.:)

Comment: If you XOR two printable characters the result won't necessarily be a printable character. It can even be 0 (if the two characters are equal), which will act as a C string terminator.

Comment: Also, you never null-terminate your output string. It's not in a static scope, so it won't be null-initialized.

Comment: @Naman Sood Moreover the array c can not contain a string because it is not zero terminated.

Comment: I tried it with two strings like HELLO and AXHJB which should give output as KMIVE but it is still giving some random unprintable characters

Comment: In the end should I give c[i]='/0' or something ?

Comment: @NamanSood I think you may be confusing alphabet indices (0-25 or 1-26) with text encoding (probably ASCII). `'H'` and `'A'` have values of 0x48 and 0x41 respectively in ASCII. `'H' ^ 'A'` is 9, which is a tab character.

Comment: "I tried it with two strings like HELLO and AXHJB which should give output as KMIVE" looks like you need something else than what everybody call XOR.

Comment: First, lowercase them and then subtract `'A'`. Then XOR it and add `'A'` back.

Comment: Looks like the Vernam Cypher uses [Baudot code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code) as it's text encoding. You need to convert to that before you perform the operation.

Comment: Or actually Baudot-Murray code (ITA2), not the original Baudot code (ITA1).

Comment: Lowercase and subtract doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

> I've been trying to make a program on Vernam Cipher which requires me to XOR two strings

Yes, it does, but that's not the *only* thing it requires.  [The Vernam cipher](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/vernam.htm) involves first ***representing the message and key in [the ITA2 encoding](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/baudot.htm)*** (also known as Baudot-Murray code), and then computing the XOR of each pair of corresponding character codes from the message and key streams.

Moreover, to display the result in the manner you indicate wanting to do, you must first ***convert it from ITA2 to the appropriate character encoding for your locale***, which is probably a superset of ASCII.

The transcoding to and from ITA2 is relatively straightforward, but not so trivial that I'm inclined to write them for you.  There is a code chart at the ITA2 link above.

Note also that ITA2 is a *stateful* encoding that includes shift codes and a null character.  This implies that the enciphered message may contain non-printing characters, which could cause some confusion, including a null character, which will be misinterpreted as a string terminator if you are not careful.  More importantly, *encoding in ITA2 may increase the length of the message* as a result of a need to insert shift codes.

Additionally, as a technical matter, if you want to treat the enciphered bytes as a C string, then you need to ensure that it is terminated with a null character.  On a related note, `scanf()` will do that for the strings it reads, which uses one character, leaving you only 49 each for the actual message and key characters.

> What is the method to XOR these two strings ?

The XOR itself is not your problem.  Your code for that is fine.  The problem is that you are XORing the wrong values, and (once the preceding is corrected) outputting the result in a manner that does not serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

*Whenever I run the code, I get output as ????? in boxes*...

`XOR`ing two printable characters does not always result in a printable value.

Consider the following:

- the `^` operator operates at the bit level.
- there is a limited range of values that are *printable*. (from *[here](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/ascii-codes-overview-of-all-characters-on-the-ascii-table/)*):

> ```
> Control Characters (0–31 & 127): Control characters are not printable characters. They are used to send commands to the PC or the
> ```
>
> printer and are based on telex technology. With these characters, you
>   can set line breaks or tabs. Today, they are mostly out of use.
>
> ```
> Special Characters (32–47 / 58–64 / 91–96 / 123–126): Special characters include all printable characters that are neither letters
> ```
>
> nor numbers. These include punctuation or technical, mathematical
>   characters. ASCII also includes the space (a non-visible but printable
>   character), and, therefore, does not belong to the control characters
>   category, as one might suspect.
>
> ```
> Numbers (30–39): These numbers include the ten Arabic numerals from 0-9.
>
> Letters (65–90 / 97–122): Letters are divided into two blocks, with the first group containing the uppercase letters and the second
> ```
>
> group containing the lowercase.

Using the following two strings and the following code:

```
char str1 = {"asdf"};
char str1 = {"jkl;"};
```

Following demonstrates XORing the elements of the strings:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str1[] = {"asdf"};
    char str2[] = {"jkl;"};

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(str1)/sizeof(str1[i]);i++)
    {
        printf("%d ^ %d: %d\n", str1[i],str2[i], str1[i]^str2[i]);
    }
    getchar();



    return 0;   
}
```

While all of the input characters are printable (except the NULL character), not all of the XOR results of corresponding characters are:

```
 97 ^ 106: 11  //not printable
115 ^ 107: 24  //not printable
100 ^ 108: 8   //not printable
102 ^ 59: 93
0 ^ 0: 0
```

This is why you are seeing the odd output.  While all of the values may be completely valid for your purposes, they are not all printable.

Comment: how would I take the input then ? same way ?

Comment: Ah I got it, I was anyways going with the wrong logic to the question. thanks for the information

Comment: He's not XOR-ing the NULL character, though.

Comment: Indeed the OP's result array is not ensured terminated, but that has very little to do with most of this answer, it it probably is not the main reason for the unexpected output.

Comment: @JL2210 You still need to null-terminate the string

Comment: @ThomasJager Ah, yes. Didn't see that.